# ORDER BY timestring as time instead of a string

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a table with a column of times such as

```
| time|
|=====|
| 9:20|
|14:33|
| 7:35|
```

In my query, I have `ORDER BY time`, but it sorts the times as strings, so the result is ordered as

```
|14:33|
| 7:35|
| 9:20|
```

What do I have to do to my ORDER BY statement to get the result to be sorted as times so it would result in

```
| 7:35|
| 9:20|
|14:33|
```

Comment: and the type of this field is.... what? if it's a text-type (char, varchar, etc...) it's entirely expected. sqlite is NOT going to pretend to be smart and sort numerically.

Comment: It's a text field. I know it won't sort numerically on its own, but surely there's a way to tell it to do so?

Comment: convert to seconds and store as a simple int.

Comment: Correct your data. Store '7:35' as `07:35', `9:20` as `09:20`, and things will sort properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to pad hours that do not include a leading 0 with one in the query itself and then perform the sort.

```
SELECT * FROM <table> ORDER BY SUBSTR('0' || time, -5, 5);
```

Here's the breakdown on what the SUBSTR method is doing.

`||` is a string concatenation operation in SQLite. So `'0' || '7:35'` will give `'07:35'`, and `'0' || '14:23'` will give `'014:23'`. Since we're only interested in a string like `HH:MM`, we only want the last 5 characters from this concatenated string.

If you store the original string with a leading 0 for hours and minutes, then you could simply order by the time column and get the desired results.

```
|14:33|
|07:35|
|09:20|
```

That will also make it easy to the use the time column as an actual time unit, and do computations on it easily. For example, if you wanted to add 20 minutes to all times, that can simply be achieved with:

```
SELECT TIME(time, '+20 minutes') FROM <table>;
```

The reason for this 0 padding is because SQLite as of now only understands 24 hour times such as `'HH:MM'` but not `'H:MM'`.

Here's a good reference page for SQLite documentation on [Date and Time related functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to store the time as seconds. Either as a unix timestamp(recommended), or as number of seconds since midnight.

In the second case, 7:35 will 7*3600+35*60=27300 and the representation for 14:33 will be 52380 Store them as integers(timestamps). Similarly for unix timestamps, times are stored as no of seconds since 1970.

You can now sort them as integers

Use utility methods to easily handle the conversion